# Guarante unique id with 16 bytes length in java

Tags: uuid

Does the combination of 8 bytes return from getLeastSignificantBits() and getMostSignificantBits() in java.util.UUID class guarante unique 16 bytes id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the UUID you're working with is unique, then yes.

Comment: (That is, it just exposes the *same UUID value* in a different way.)